# Use of a single LineString to display two data fields

Tags: python, plot, geopandas, shapely

I have a recurring problem for which I cannot find an easy solution, whereas I guess there is one.

I have a dataset representing road traffic data at a street level. This dataset is associated with a road network graph, where each edge represents a road and each node represents an intersection. For each edge, I have a `shapely` *LineString* object containing the geopgraphic properties of the road.

My goal is to draw a map representing this traffic dataset. I can do that quite easily using `geopandas` for example, but my problem comes from the fact that most roads, even when bi-directionnal, are represented with a single *LineString* object, so one of the direction won't be seen as both will be plotted on top of each other.

Would there be a simple way to solve this problem? Ideally, I would like to end up with a plot like this: [image: traffic data representation example]

Comment: Maybe you could duplicate the line and then translate it by a few pixels? it won't be perfect, but the separation will hopefully be apparent.

Comment: That's a way I thought about, but considering that edges are not necessarily straight, and with every possible orientation, it gets complicated. I will probably end up doing it that way if there is no easy solution. Another solution that I don't like very much would be to draw one data with a plain line and the other one with a dashed line on top. Such a map would be quite hard to read I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following snippet use offset_curve to double up a line string, which is I think what you are looking for.

```
data = np.array([np.linspace(0,10), np.sin(np.linspace(0,10))])
road = shapely.LineString(data.T)
constant = 0.1
big_road = shapely.MultiLineString([road.offset_curve(constant), road.offset_curve(-constant)])
```

which gives:

```
from shapely import plotting
plotting.plot_line(big_road)
plt.savefig('example.jpg')
```

[image]

Comment: This is great and exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I didn't know this _offset_curve()_ function.